# Chrome debugger doesn't show variable values on mouse over

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I created a simple react app by using "**npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript**" command. When I start the app "**npm start**" it is running with no issues but I'm not able to see the values in the Chrome dev tools if I add a breakpoint in the code. Am I missing any dependency or this is the way it's supposed to work for the react app?

[Mouse hovered on name variable but didn't popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3qUu.png)

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in devtools in my case, I've fixed it by changing an unrelated setting:

1. open devtools, then its preferences
2. toggle `Display variable values inline while debugging`

   [image]
3. close devtools
4. repeat 1-2 if necessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I toggled it on and off and then reopened devtools. Btw I tried to debug this app in edge as well and behavior is same, looks like it's not a browser related issue. Also I tried angular app in chrome it's working as expected I'm so confused.

Comment: The idea was to turn it off, close devtools, then turn it on.

Comment: Yes I followed the exact steps you mentioned, didn't work :(
But it's working fine if I setup some vanilla js app. The problem is only with React Js

Comment: Toggling it re-enabled inline variable values, after you step over in-scope, but not mouse over. I have to copy/paste the variable name into the console to see what's assigned before evaluation. WTH.

Comment: Seriously, it feels like this functionality drops out once a month. We need a permanent fix. Unacceptable Chrome team!

Comment: Another user fixed it by changing "Show detailed inspect tooltip" in the settings (Elements section).

Comment: I have similar issues with debugging `*.vue` in chrome dev tools while plain `*.js` has no issues at all. To see inline values of variable on mouse over, one has to select whole variable name (double click on variable) then variable value will be shown.

Answer (score -1):

I find this problem when I debug typescript. I have tried this steps, but it didn't work too

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a typescript problem.

Comment: Some times ,it didn't work with javascript.

Comment: This really does not qualify as an answer. Probably better to move it in a comment to the suggestion you are referring to.